# Mystery div appearing in code with "data-original-title" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

A div is being added by something in the code of the website I am working on. About a hundred different devs have hacked away at this over the years.

The page uses Bootstrap and is built upon a .Net forms site. There are a few panels and runat server buttons on the page.

The div in question appears after a button and is creating this div off the page causing a scrollbar to appear on the body.

If anyone knows what code is adding this div please let me know. I have spent the better part of the past few days trying to track it down.

```
<span id="lblBuilderSelectedOptionApiReadyDate"></span>

<button id="_ctl0_body_btnBuilderSelectedOptionApiReprocess" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-success disabled" onclick="ReprocessBuilderSelectedOptionAPI()" disabled="disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>&nbsp;Reprocess</button>

<div style="height: 22px; width: 84.7031px; position: absolute; top: 1460.38px; left: 565.328px;" data-original-title="" title=""></div>
```

There is one reference in the entire solution to "data-original-title" and it is in the bootstrap css. abbr[title], abbr[data-original-title] { cursor: help; border-bottom: 1px dotted #777; }

Comment: It could be any number of things. You should try seeing if there's anything attached to the `div` to help track down the source of it, such as classes, ids, etc.

Comment: There is one reference in the entire solution to "data-original-title" and it is in the bootstrap css.

abbr[title],
abbr[data-original-title] {
  cursor: help;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #777;
}

Comment: BTW: @Spangle I added a code snippet but it did not appear. It took a few tries editing and saving to make it work.

Comment: Probably is not in the code base, but created in the cms (if you have one, I do not know) Is there a section in the cms for creating divs? If so, search for the inline styles there to locate the div. Also search the db for those inline styles.

Comment: No CMS the site is more of an application. All content is data driven. Customer records, inventory etc...I was actually thinking that there may be a an external .js file linked somewhere and that the code that is doing it is outside of the solution but it does not appear to be the case either. .

Comment: And in your code base, is there anything under the ```<button id="_ctl0_body_btnBuilderSelectedOptionApiReprocess"```

Comment: No its blank in the html. That div gets inserted right at that point. I have looked through the runat server for that button and all it does is hide or show the button.

Comment: Is there any other reference to that ```_ctl0_body_btnBuilderSelectedOptionApiReprocess``` in your code base? If you remove it, does the blank div still git inserted? Also, is it inserted at the end of your document?

Comment: Just this:
 
    private void DisableBuilderApiReprocesButton()
        {
            btnBuilderSelectedOptionApiReprocess.Disabled = true;
            btnBuilderSelectedOptionApiReprocess.Attributes["class"] = "btn btn-default btn-xs btn-success disabled";
        }

Comment: Also, if you move the button around, is the div always inserted after it? Just debugging if it is related to that button or not.

Comment: Removing the Button does in fact cause the page to not insert the div. So that's progress I guess. I am going to try moving it around.

Comment: Yes the div is added right after the button. This seems to indicate that something about that button is the culprit. I will start digging through the code for any jQuery or other JS that searches for or attaches itself to buttons.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a JS/jQuery response, but I would also try looking the string from a shell, searching through the files in the web folder, if that string exists

If you have access to a console on the server, you could try:

```
grep -rnw '/path/to/web/folder/' -e 'original-title'
```

I hope this can give you some approach, regards!